# Mvc4 Web API - Turn off help pages for specific Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have my Web API controller set up
I have the help pages working
But I don't want certain API Controllers to show in the help pages

How can I stop an API Controller appearing in the Help Pages?

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by **help pages**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decorate the controller with the following attribute and setting:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
```

Comment: That worked! I'mm have to read up on the System.Web.Http.Description namespace! - Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following before the class, or before a control method.

```
 using System.Web.Http.Description;
 //you have to use above namespace to use the code below.
 [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
```

If you use that before the class the whole controller class will  be ignored. You will not find a heading with the particular controller therefore.

If you use this before a controller method, then only that controller will be neglected and not shown on the help page.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable all controllers (usually we have a lot of them), create a new controller as base for those controllers.

```
/// <summary>
/// Base api controller for all controllers
/// </summary>
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{...
```

Then place the new base controller as parent of the current controllers.

```
public class MyController: BaseController
```

All controllers will be disabled for help page